# How to remove the border on the hover element in nvd3

Tags: css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to display the d3 charting. im trying to remove the border that is around the info text on hover over the data points. below is the image:

[image]

when i hover over the data point the info text shows up and the border, im trying to remove that border in css.
any ideas how???

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you have a look what CSS rule(s) apply to that frame?

Comment: Are you talking about the border with rounded corners in your image, or the outer one with square corners? I've only ever seen the square one.

Comment: the border outside the rounded border one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
.nvtooltip{
  border:0px;
}
```